# How to start the Activity Indicator Loading as soon as I press the button?

Tags: swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I have created an activity indicator in my application:

```
  @IBAction func LocateMe(sender: AnyObject) {
    Loading.hidden = false
    Loading.startAnimating()

}
```

In the ViewDidLoad is hidden and when I click on the button LocateMe I want to start seeing it loading on the screen. 
The problem is that it starts loading but very late, it starts when the app opens the next view controller.
Do you have any ideas how can I start displaying it on the screen as soon as the user clicks on the button. It is useless if the user waits and there isn't an indicator which shows him that the action is done. I am open also for examples too.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import SwiftyJSON
import SVProgressHUD

 struct City {

let name : String
let location : CLLocation
let description :String
let imageName : NSURL
let fileLink : NSURL

func distanceTo(location:CLLocation) -> Int
{
    let distanceMeters = location.distanceFromLocation(self.location)
    let distanceKilometers = distanceMeters / 1000.00
    return Int(round(100 * distanceKilometers) / 100)
}
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var Loading: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var LocateMeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var LabelTest: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var LabelValueSlider: UILabel!
var MySliderCurrentValue = Double()

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var userLoc : CLLocation!
var cities = [City]()
var nearbyCities = [City]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Loading.hidden = true
    LocateMeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cities", ofType: "json") as String!
    let path = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.99website.eu/citiescopy.json")!) as NSData!
    // let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
    var error : NSError?
    let ReadableJSON2 = JSON ( data:path, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error )
    print(error)

    do {
        let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(path!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
        for city in jsonObject["cities"] as! [[String:AnyObject]] {
            //let coordinates = position["Position"] as! [String:CLLocationDegrees]
            let cityName = city["Name"] as! String
            let latitude = city["Latitude"] as! Double
            let longitude = city["Longitude"] as! Double
            let description = city["Description"] as! String
            let image = city["Image"] as! String
            let lin = city["Link"] as! String
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let city = City(name: cityName, location: location,description: description, imageName: NSURL( string: image )!, fileLink: NSURL( string: lin )! )

            cities.append(city)

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    if locationManager.respondsToSelector(#selector(locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }


}
```

Comment: What other code are you executing when you call `LocateMe`. Are you staring any location services? Are you loading a new `UIViewController`? You maybe doing something on the main thread that is blocking the animation.

Comment: Yes I am starting a location, wait I can upload the whole code

Comment: Try to comment out this line of code. It causes the main thread to freeze. `let path = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.99website.eu/citiescopy.json")!) as NSData!`. Try to run it in background thread or use GCD. Use this sample code `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    //All stuff here
})`

Comment: sorry but if I comment the first line I will not be able to load my json file.

Comment: also where should I write this code : dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIO‌​RITY_DEFAULT, 0), { //All stuff here })

Comment: First of all you need to be clear on use case here. If anything is depending upon that JSON file then show busy indicator till that file is loaded. It is never be a good idea to download data from internet on main thread in viewDidLoad method. `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
    // do network task & parsing here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        // update some UI
    }
}` is the swift sample code.

Comment: can you give me an example of "busy indicator" I am a swift beginner and do not know that indicator

Answer (score 0):

What I believe to be your issue is what @AsadAli was stating. Your loading data on the main thread which is synchronously. What you should try to do is move that to a background thread (asynchronously) so your UI won't be blocked.

You could do something like this:

```
/**
 Loads the JSON data asyncrounously

 - parameter urlString:  the URL
 - parameter completion: call on the main thread when the transaction is complete. Returning the data if it's there and an error if one exist.
 */
func loadJSONAsync(urlString: String, completion:(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) ->()) {

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                completion(data: nil, error: error)
            }
            else {
                completion(data: data, error: nil)
            }
        })
    }).resume()
}
```

then call it like this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
    loadJSONAsync("") { (data, error) in

        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
        else {
            //process JSON data
        }

    }
```

Which just to quickly clean up your `viewDidLoad` I would structure it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Loading.hidden = true
    LocateMeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5


    //
    // You should start showing a loading wheel heree
    //

    //Load the JSON
    loadJSONAsync("http://www.99website.eu/citiescopy.json") { (data, error) in

        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
        else {
            processJSON(data)
        }
    }

    // Start your location manager
    startLocationManager()

}

func processJSON(data: NSData) {
    var error : NSError?
    let ReadableJSON2 = JSON ( data:path, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error )
    print(error)

    do {
        let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(path!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
        for city in jsonObject["cities"] as! [[String:AnyObject]] {
            //let coordinates = position["Position"] as! [String:CLLocationDegrees]
            let cityName = city["Name"] as! String
            let latitude = city["Latitude"] as! Double
            let longitude = city["Longitude"] as! Double
            let description = city["Description"] as! String
            let image = city["Image"] as! String
            let lin = city["Link"] as! String
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let city = City(name: cityName, location: location,description: description, imageName: NSURL( string: image )!, fileLink: NSURL( string: lin )! )

            cities.append(city)

            //
            // You should stop showing a loading wheel heree
            //

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
}

func startLocationManager() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    if locationManager.respondsToSelector(#selector(locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
    else {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

/**
 Loads the JSON data asyncrounously

 - parameter urlString:  the URL
 - parameter completion: call on the main thread when the transaction is complete. Returning the data if it's there and an error if one exist.
 */
func loadJSONAsync(urlString: String, completion:(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) ->()) {

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: urlString)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                completion(data: nil, error: error)
            }
            else {
                completion(data: data, error: nil)
            }
        })
    }).resume()
}
```

...also your variable names should be declared with a lower case :)